# Load Iframes in a page with interval time

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a php page that i need load Iframes in a interval time like 1 Second

```
<iframe id="content_window" width="100%" height="100" style="width:
100%; height:100px;border: 0px;" src="http://LINK1" FRAMEBORDER="0"></iframe>
<p><strong>
<iframe id="content_window" width="100%" height="100" style="width: 
100%; height: 100px; border: 0px;" src="http://LINK2" FRAMEBORDER="0"></iframe>
<p><strong>
<iframe id="content_window" width="100%" height="100" style="width: 100%;
height: 100px; border: 0px;" src="http://LINK3" FRAMEBORDER="0"></iframe>
```

I have 3 Iframes in the same page i need to load one by one after 1s or 2s interval It possible

Comment: Can you show me please how can i do it

Comment: Using JavaScript, you can just put the urls for the iFrames in an array, use the setInterval method to set the source of each iFrame with a counter.

Comment: I'm not an expert in codes , can you please make an example